# Excel VBA: Adding Array to Form Control Combobox

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox

I have several files I want to combine and analyse with one results file. One of those files contains samples with different names that are repeated an unknown amount of times. I want to extact all unknown names from this file and add them  to a dropdown box (Form Control Combobox).

To simplify things I added the following strings to the first column a sheet in a new Excel file:

> String 1
>
> String 1
>
> String 2
>
> String 3
>
> String 3
>
> String 3
>
> String 4
>
> String 4

to extract the unique strings, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
Sub MakeArrayInDropDown()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim myArray() As Variant    ' Array with undefined size
    Dim i As Integer            ' Counter for-loop
    Dim i_UnStr As Integer      ' Counter of unique strings
    Dim i_lastStr As Integer    ' Length of strings in column A
    Dim wb As Workbook          ' Short workbookname
    Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Short worksheet name
    Dim TC As Range             ' Target Cell (TC)

    ' Set workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Set cell where all unique strings should go to
    Set TC = ws.Cells(1, 3)

    ' Determine amount of strings in column A
    i_lastStr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Go through all strings that are in column A
    For i = 1 To i_lastStr

        ' Save the first string in the first position of the array
        If i_UnStr = 0 Then
            i_UnStr = 1
            ReDim myArray(i_UnStr)                      ' Resize array to 1
            myArray(i_UnStr) = ws.Cells(i, 1)           ' Add first string to array

        ' Add if next string is different from the string previously added
        ElseIf Not StrComp(myArray(i_UnStr), ws.Cells(i, 1)) = 0 Then
            ' Increase unique strings counter
            i_UnStr = i_UnStr + 1
            ' Resize array to no unique strings, preserving precious values
            ReDim Preserve myArray(i_UnStr)
            ' Add next unique string to array as well
            myArray(i_UnStr) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Add Form Control dropdown to target cell
    ws.DropDowns.Add(TC.Left, TC.Top, TC.Width, TC.Height).Name = "dropdown_row" & TC.Row
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).ControlFormat.List = myArray
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this code results in the following error:

> Runtime error 1004: Unable to set the List property of the Dropdown class

I don't understand what is wrong withmy array, because if I change the last line into

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).ControlFormat.List = _
    Array(myArray(1), myArray(2), myArray(3), myArray(4))
```

Everything works perfectly fine. It seems like my array is not accepted as such...

Also, initially I wrote the last line like this

```
ws.Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).ControlFormat.List = myArray
```

But that gave me:

> Runtime error 424: object required

Can anybody explain me why any of these two things are wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `List` and `AddItem` are methods not properties.  `List` only accepts index values.

Comment: Thank you Cyboashu, why is the array I created not an index value while the other array is? It probably has something to do with the empty value at index 0 as well, but I cannot grasp it yet. I like the explanation of David (asnwer below), that the array cannot contain mixed types and that a vbNullString would solve that issue. Is that the simple way of saying that it only accepts index values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and my observations as follows:

The DropDown shape does not like the `Empty` value at index `0` of your array. It seems that you are not able to use mixed type in the array you're passing to the `.List` method, because even if I change the `Empty` value to an integer, it fails with the same error.

Regarding why this statement works:

> ```
> wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).ControlFormat.List = _
> Array(myArray(1), myArray(2), myArray(3), myArray(4))
> ```

The above works because you're passing an array that avoids the pitfall mentioned above, because you're explicitly *not* passing the `Empty` value.

**Note:** Strictly speaking, there is no need for you to `ReDim` your array when `i_UnStr = 0`, arrays are normally base 0, so you can just work with it that way.

Alternatively, you can force a null string in to the first array item, and this should work:

```
myArray(0) = vbNullString
ws.Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).ControlFormat.List = myArray
```

So, the solution is to avoid mixed data type (and possibly also the unnecessary empty element in the array), or if you need a "blank", you need to assign it as an empty string either `vbNullString` or literal `""`.

In terms of optimisation, I'd avoid the array altogether especially if the data is large, because `ReDim Preserve` is usually a rather expensive statement.

```
Sub MakeArrayInDropDown()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim i As Integer            ' Counter for-loop
    Dim i_lastStr As Integer    ' Length of strings in column A
    Dim wb As Workbook          ' Short workbookname
    Dim ws As Worksheet         ' Short worksheet name
    Dim TC As Range             ' Target Cell (TC)
    Dim DD As Shape             ' Dropdown shape
    ' Set workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Set cell where all unique strings should go to
    Set TC = ws.Cells(1, 3)

    ' Determine amount of strings in column A
    i_lastStr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Add Form Control dropdown to target cell
    Set DD = ws.DropDowns.Add(TC.Left, TC.Top, TC.Width, TC.Height)
    DD.Name = "dropdown_row" & TC.Row
    DD.AddItem ""  'Adds a blank entry in the first row of the dropdown
    DD.AddItem ws.Cells(i,1).Value
    For i = 2 To i_lastStr
        ' Add if next string is different from the string previously added
        ElseIf Not StrComp(ws.Cells(i-1, 1), ws.Cells(i, 1)) = 0 Then
            DD.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply, I was using the array so I could add it to multiple comboboxes. I would get the array from one file and then add the same combobox for each entry of data mined from another file. In this way I avoid reading the strings from the first file multiple times.
Although this code is working perfectly fine, it only allows me to make one combobox.
Is there any way to avoid forming/erasing the myArray(0), or loading it with a string? Or maybe copying the whole combobox into another (I did not search for that yet)

Comment: Did this answer your original question?

Comment: It might have because I apparently did not ask for the right question, should I adapt my question such that the combobox should be filled with an array always?

Comment: @Adriaan I showed how to do it *both* ways, with and without arrays, and identified the problem being mixed data type in the array. I'm not sure what else you need at this point, but probably it's best suited to accept this answer and ask a new question with specific problem you're encountering by adopting one (or the other) of these solutions..

Comment: You are right, except that the addition of myArray(0) = vbNullString still generates the 424 error when I use _ws_ as worksheet name instead of the _wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")_. I am sorry for not being so clear, it has been a long day looking at similar code the whole day...

Answer (score 0):

Please, Try this:

```
ws.Shapes("dropdown_row" & TC.Row).OLEFormat.Object.List = myArray
```